# Data ingestion to ML Via SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, marklogic

I have created Bean which is a composite bean(hold instances of other beans).Declared with notation so that it treats the object data as xml data.The below villageInvigilator bean holds person,user and address objects.I have declared those classes with xml annotations(xml binding).Now am trying to send the xml data over post rest call to dump the data into ML but its been failed due to the below error.Can someone help me whats went wrong in the below code.

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java class com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart, and Java type class com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart, and MIME media type multipart/mixed; boundary=Boundary_2_1591997445_1586182536010 was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter$RequestEntityWriterImpl.<init>(RequestWriter.java:199) ~[jersey-client-1.19.4.jar:1.19.4]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.getRequestEntityWriter(RequestWriter.java:248) ~[jersey-client-1.19.4.jar:1.19.4]
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.getHttpEntity(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:241) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.getUriHttpRequest(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:197) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:153) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.17.jar:1.17]
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.DigestChallengeFilter.handle(DigestChallengeFilter.java:34) ~[marklogic-client-api-4.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPDigestAuthFilter.handle(HTTPDigestAuthFilter.java:494) ~[jersey-client-1.19.4.jar:1.19.4]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.4.jar:1.19.4]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.4.jar:1.19.4]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.4.jar:1.19.4]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.put(WebResource.java:539) ~[jersey-client-1.19.4.jar:1.19.4]
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.putPostDocumentImpl(JerseyServices.java:1503) ~[marklogic-client-api-4.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.putDocument(JerseyServices.java:1199) ~[marklogic-client-api-4.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.write(DocumentManagerImpl.java:919) ~[marklogic-client-api-4.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.write(DocumentManagerImpl.java:757) ~[marklogic-client-api-4.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.write(DocumentManagerImpl.java:701) ~[marklogic-client-api-4.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.kc.serviceImplementation.VillageInspectorOperationsImpl.villageInspectorRegistration(VillageInspectorOperationsImpl.java:112) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.kc.web.VillageInspectorRESTController.createUser(VillageInspectorRESTController.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
```

```
package com.kissan.datatypes;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "villageInspector")
public class VillageInspector {

    private String id;
    private Person person;
    private User user;
    private Address address;

    public VillageInspector() {

    }

    public VillageInspector(String id, Person person, User user, Address address) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.person = person;
        this.user = user;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

Implementation code:

```
public void villageInspectorRegistration(VillageInspector villageInspector) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DocumentMetadataHandle metadata = new DocumentMetadataHandle();
        List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
        str.add("villageInspectors");
        metadata.getCollections().addAll(str);

        JAXBHandle<VillageInspector> contentHandle = getUserDetailsHandle();
        contentHandle.set(villageInspector);
        xmlDocumentManager.write(commonUtils.getDocId(villageInspector.getId(),objectType), metadata, contentHandle);


    }


private JAXBHandle<VillageInspector> getUserDetailsHandle() {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(VillageInspector.class);
            return new JAXBHandle<VillageInspector>(context);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to create Village Inspector JAXB context", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you call toString() on the contentHandle after setting the value instead of calling write() on the xmlDocumentManager, do you get a valid string representation of the XML?  If so, does a write() operation without the metadata succeed?

Comment: Data is loading successfully when i don't use the metadata.But i want to add few collections while ingesting the data to ML.I have tried to set the collections using the below snippet ,but leads to the earlier mentioned user. Couldn't able to add the collections. ``` DocumentMetadataHandle metadataHandle = new DocumentMetadataHandle(); DocumentCollections collections = metadataHandle.getCollections(); collections.addAll("/latest/user", "/latest/villageInspector"); ``` used metadataHandle.setFormat(Format.XML); as well.

Comment: Given that data loads successfully without metadata, it doesn't seem to be a JAXB problem.  Instead, it seems to be a problem with sending a multipart. As I read the error message, the JerseyClient doesn't know how to write the  Jersey MultiPart class. Perhaps you have incompatible Jersey versions?  By the way, the Java API switched from JerseyClient to OKHttpClient some years back.  Are you using a version of the Java API that's compatible with your MarkLogic version?

Comment: I'm not using either Jersey or OkHttpClient in the project,using the spring-boot-starter-web to support rest services.Anyway defined rest call to get input data but using marklogic client api to dump the data to ML,in that case probably it would be issue with xmlDocumentManager.write which is supported by marklogic client api.

Comment: I checked, and the change from JerseyClient to OKHttpClient was checked into the Java API on August of 2014 -- see https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/issues/65 . You might want to verify that you are using the correct version of the Java API for your MarkLogic server.  If you have a support contract with MarkLogic, you could also get guidance there.

Comment: Thank you so much ehennum, initially i thought you were asking about service info w.r.to spring.But as per last comment,i understand that internally ML client api uses okhttp to process the requests.Earlier i have used 4.0.1 and its changed to 4.0.3.Its started working.

Comment: Great, glad to hear the upgrade solved the problem.